# Smooth Streaming with PlayReady Licensing on Chromecast

Tags: encryption, google-cast, chromecast

Using the latest Google ChromeCast SDK, I am able to play non-encrypted SmoothStreaming assets through the chromecast with the MediaLibrary and by passing the Manifest url. However, I am not able to get encrypted files working. I have tried setting the licenseUrl field on the host object, constructing the object with the license url, and calling updateLicenseRequestInfo with a url to the license.

The assets I am testing with are:

Working, non-encrypted manifest:
http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/ISMAAACLC/Taxi3_AACLC.ism/Manifest

PlayReady manifest:
playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/ISMAAACLCPR/Taxi3_AACLC.ism/Manifest
License url:
http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/svc/rightsmanager.asmx?PlayRight=1&UseSimpleNonPersistentLicense=1

In silverlight, I have the option to overload onAcquireLicense through a manual license acquirer. This enables me to obtain the challenge string, pass this to a custom license service I have built, generate a license, and pass this back through the processLicense method. Is such a custom licensing scheme supported by chromecast?

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing the same URL and it's working for me perfectly.

Did you modified the supported extensions from ".ism" to ".ism/Manifest"? That's the only changed I've done to test the SmoothStreaming/PlayReady streams and everything works like a charm.

Comment: Are you testing with the license? How do you set the license url?

Comment: It just work, you only need to set an SmoothStreaming protocol for the manifest URL and that's it. The license must be declared inside the manifest so it parses the XML and gets the keys automatically.

Comment: That isn't an option in my case as the url is not static. It includes challenge info and some parameters, so needs to be specified at runtime.

Comment: Oh, I see. I had the same problem and AFAIK the url cannot contain any parameter, it won't work because of the way that the MediaLibrary handles/parses the data. You can try passing the parameters through headers within the requests.

Comment: Here: Check the "Host" section: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player

There you can see how to send parameters within the headers and retrieve them then onto the server. I think it's the only way to do it right now, but maybe some Google engineer can help us with this (fingers crossed)

Comment: Even then, no luck. I removed the query params which are optional and am still getting a Fatal Error 2 in the receiver after it logs "keyNeeded" and "Creating Session". I am setting the url with updateLicenseRequestInfo the same way as in the example there.

Comment: Are you using samples without any modification?

Comment: Yes. Only modification is that listed above.

Comment: Let me take a look into it and I'll share the code with you ;)